# Select2: unselecting one item in the selected list causes all the items to be unselected

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-select2

I have an edit form which using select2 multiple choice.

I using ajax to load list items and initSelection to select the items stored in the database. I rendered well

But when I deselect or select any item, all other items deselect.

My code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control js-select2" multiple id="merchants" name="merchants" data-shop="{{implode(',', $detail['merchants'])}}" data-placeholder="All store domain" style="width: 100%;">
    </select>
</div>
```

```js
let start = 0;
$(".js-select2").select2({
  closeOnSelect : false,
  tags: true,
  multiple: true,
  minimumInputLength: 0,
  minimumResultsForSearch: 0,
  width: '100%',
  ajax: {
    url: '/api/merchant/list',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      var query = {
        search: {
          value: params.term ?? null,
          regex: false
        },
        start
      }

      return query;
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
      start = data.more ? start + 10 : 0;
      const merchantStrings = $('#merchants').data('shop').toString();
      const merchants = typeof merchantStrings === 'string' ? merchantStrings.split(",") : [];
      let shopIds = [];
      $.each(merchants, function(index, value) {
          shopIds.push(parseInt(value, 10));
      });
      let modifiedData = data.data.map( function (item) {
        // Set the `selected` property based on some condition
        const option = {
          id: item.shopify_store_id,
          text: item.shopify_store_domain,
          selected: !!shopIds.includes(item.shopify_store_id)
        };

        return option;
      });
      return {
        results: modifiedData,
        pagination: {
            more: data.more
        }
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  initSelection: function (element, callback) {
    const merchantStrings = $('#merchants').data('shop').toString();
    const merchants = typeof merchantStrings === 'string' ? merchantStrings.split(",") : [];
    let shopIds = [];
    $.each(merchants, function(index, value) {
        shopIds.push(parseInt(value, 10));
    });
    if (shopIds !== "") {
      $.ajax('/api/merchant/get-by-ids', {
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          ids: shopIds
        },
        dataType: 'json'
      }).done(function (response) {
          let selectedItems = [];
          $.each(response, function (index, value) {
            selectedItems.push({
              id: value.id,
              text: value.shopify_domain,
              selected: true
            });
          });
          callback(selectedItems);
      });
    }
});
```

I still haven't found a solution or what's wrong with my code.

Comment: try to use multiple="multiple" in html.  and don't use multiple: true in the script